# I am afraid to install Nvidia Drivers and break stuff

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm currently running 13.04 on my production machine (which I rely heavily on for work). I currently don't have any external storage to do SSD clone to, but I'm really temped to install nvidia drivers.

The nouveau ones are just too bad, the Unity feels sluggish, there is tearing of screen in even basic terminal apps like vim, browsers are slow and choppy, YouTube takes 10 seconds to switch to fullscreen.

I'be been running 13.04 beta1 for a while, and I had installed nvidia drivers from blob, and manually linked opengl 32bit libraries. It worked for a while, but crashed the system miserably few updates later.

Also, I am running customly compiled kernel (basically  3.8.0-19-generic that ships with 13.04 anyway, just having 1 commit removed which breaks sound). I have kernel-headers with it too.

I am tempted to use `Additional Drivers` utility to install Drivers, but I know it has never ever worked for me in the past.

I don't know if binary blob from nvidia.com is safe either.

What would be the safest way to install drivers at this point? I will try and get some hdd to make a backup tomorrow.

P.S.: Never had problems with kmod-nvidia in Fedora. I'm new to Ubuntu tho. Card is 560Ti.

Comment: Did you get a change to go through this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia?

Comment: seems quite old. would installing from ppa and running nvidia-config and xorg config manually work?

Comment: I have done manually only and it works properly for me. Do you want  the steps to install and configure?

Comment: Yes please. I will probably install dummy 13.04 with same kernel and see if it works fine there first. Than Ill try on production.

Comment: Please accept the answer that answered it for you, or add the details of what you did in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to install nvidia driver in Ubuntu

http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/05/ubuntu-nvidia-driver-installation.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to    include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also this looks like your personal blog, please make a statment to that effect, ex "On my blog, you can find..." so we do not mistake this answer as self-promotion or spam, http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3036/should-an-answer-that-is-a-link-to-the-answerers-personal-blog-be-flagged-as-spa

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me. Although the Nvidia driver does not show up under "Additional Drivers" under Xubuntu 13.04, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with the stock 3.8.0-19-generic kernel in raring and nvidia, you may want to use a [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme) then install the `nvidia-313-updates` and `nvidia-settings-313-updates` packages
Currently using xubuntu 13.04 with the 3.9 kernel and nvidia 313 driver, i have a GTX 550 TI